# Bad regression predictions with probability values

Tags: regression, probability, logistic

I have to pull through a regression on a set of probabilities (so values between 0 and 1). Those probabilities are related to a binary variable, which I have to forecast exactly.

My code basically uses a logit transformation to make the probability data "wider" and then calculate the betas and the forecasts (based on out-of-sample information); then it makes a logit transformation and gives 1 or 0 to the forecasts if their value is over or below 0.5.

The R squared and other performance measures tell me that the regression works fine for in-sample data but those forecast really tell me another story (they float around 0.52-0.55).

Has anybody got any suggestion about this problem or how to better my procedure?

P.S. I already tried logistic regression (always with the >0.5 classification method) but I obtained same results.

Comment: Is this time series data I assume? If so, are you accounting for time trends and stationarity?

Comment: You might consider beta regression as a formal alternative to your inverse logit approach. But from your description my feeling is that this won't substantially change the results. Might be worth trying, though.

Comment: The timespan is quite short so the effect should not be very important, anyway I'll give a try to removing them.

I never heard of Beta Regression but I'll look straight at that .